# projecteuler14: Assigning a variable to a function?

Tags: python, loops, variables, assign

I am wondering why this code prints 1 when I call the max() function? I want it to return 525 (the maximum length that can be created from the numbers below 1 million by the collatz function). I am new to python, and was just wondering what I am misunderstanding!

Question: https://projecteuler.net/problem=14 (I know the solution is not full)

```
def collatz(n):
    count = 1
    while n > 1:
        count += 1
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n/2
        else:
            n = 3*n + 1
    return count


def max():
    greatest = 1
    for i in xrange(1000000):
        length = collatz(i)
        if length > greatest:
            length = greatest
    return greatest

print max()
```

Comment: Did you mean to do `greatest = length`?

Answer (score 4):

The value of `greatest` is never updated inside the for-loop of function `max`.  This line is backwards:

```
length = greatest
```

It should be:

```
greatest = length
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have done wrong assignment.
Use length = greatest in place of greatest = length